# Node.js request web page

Tags: node.js, http

I need to connect to a web page and return the status code of the page, which I've been able to achieve using `http.request` however the pages I need to request can take a long time, sometimes several minutes, so I'm always getting a `socket hang up` error.

I'm using the following code so far:

```
var reqPage = function(urlString, cb) {
    // Resolve the URL
    var path = url.parse(urlString);
    var req = http.request({
        host: path.hostname,
        path: path.pathname,
        port: 80,
        method: 'GET'
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        cb.call(this, res);
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        winston.error(e.message);
    });
};
```

What do I need to do to ensure that my application still attempts to connect to the page even if it's going to take a few minutes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module and set the timeout option to an appropriate value (in milliseconds)

```
var request = require('request')
var url = 'http://www.google.com' // input your url here

// use a timeout value of 10 seconds
var timeoutInMilliseconds = 10*1000
var opts = {
  url: url,
  timeout: timeoutInMilliseconds
}

request(opts, function (err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.dir(err)
    return
  }
  var statusCode = res.statusCode
  console.log('status code: ' + statusCode)
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It's been requesting the page for a couple of minutes now and not given up. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, after a while I got `ECONNREFUSED` once I requested the second page.

Comment: That is probably something to do with the server. That said you could use the whilst function of the async module to retry each request until it succeeds. https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst

Comment: Hmm, the page it's connecting to is a PHP script running on an Apache server. The script runs `set_time_limit(0);` so the content is always finally delivered and if I connect directly to the page, the request completes.

Comment: `var timeoutInMilliseconds = 10*10000` means 100 seconds. Please correct.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev fixed. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

Add this if you don't want to use a higher level http client like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) , then add this...

```
req.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.setTimeout((1000*60*5)); //5 mins  
});
```

Comment: Even with this I get `socket hangup`.

Comment: Are you sure that a successful connection is ever made? Have you confirmed that you got a connection and that the connection times out because of no data response? You could add logging to the "connection" event and also log on the socket "close" event. I'd also add a logging statement to the socket "error" event so see what's happening there. Given what you've described it seems likely the server you're connecting to is the one dropping the connection, in which case no client configuration will fix that. Firewalls timeouts may be plaguing you if sockets are inactive for to long.